# I cant pick a choice after looping

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def print_menu():
    print('1. American')
    print('2. Asian')
    print('3. Indian')
    print('4. Mexican')
    print('5. French')
    print('6. Italian')
    print('7. Seafood')
    print('8. Pizza')
print_menu()
menu = input('\nChoose where you want to eat from-->')
if menu == "1":
    def american_menu():
        print('1. Dempsey Burger Pub')
        print('2. Redrock Canyon Grill-Wichita')
        print("3. Cheddar's Scratch Kitchen")
        print("4. Neighbors| Restaurant & Bar")
        print("5. The Kitchen")
        print("6. Firebirds Wood Fired Grill")
        print("7. Chicken and Pickle")
    american_menu()
    american = input("\nChoose which American Restaurant--> ")
    if american == "1":
        print("\nCall Dempsey Burger Pub")
        

    while True:
        go_back = input("Will you like to try another menu option?: ")
        if go_back == "Yes":
            print_menu()
        else:
            print("We'll continue with your current choice")
        break
```

so i tried looping it so it goes back to choose again from the Cuisines and moving on to where you want to eat but so far, it just asks the go_back, after i say yes...it keeps repeating the go_back again
any help will be appreciated. Thanks. i want it to loop back to the choices, pick the choice and sub-choice i selected rather than it just picking the choice and not do anything. Thanks again

NB:this is an assignment and i am stuck plus i had a list of the choices but couldnt post it due to the site.

Comment: What does `print_menu()` do?  If that goes back to the start of the same function, you're going to re-enter another version of that same loop, and you'll have to break out of it *twice* (plus one for every "yes") to actually get all the way out.

Comment: so the print menu was a list of cuisines i made, now, the code is, if someone doesnt like the choice they made, they can go back to the Cuisines menu and choose from it and it'll ask them what place they want to eat at but for some reason, it just asks for the cuisines and not restaurant

Comment: That doesn't clear anything up, because I can't tell from that description whether the code you shared is part of `print_menu` or not.  Maybe you should share the code in its entirety?

Comment: def print_menu():
xxxx
print_menu()
menu=input('choose where you want to eat from')
if menu=="1":
    def american_menu()
     american_menu()
     american=input(choose which american restaurant)
      if american==1

          insert from while true here
new to stacks so dont know how i can share the code properly

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of posting code in comments, since comments don't preserve the formatting.

Comment: done it already

Answer (score 0):

Write a while loop for `print_menu` and change `continue` with `break`

```
def print_menu():
    while True:
    #Use 2 while loops if you want. But the loop you are using is not needed  

while True:
    go_back = input("Will you like to try another menu option?: ")
    if go_back == "Yes":
        print_menu()
        break
    else:
        print("We'll continue with your current choice")
        break
```

Second Option:

```
def print_menu():
    while True:
    #Just use "while" here instead of the second one

go_back = input("Will you like to try another menu option?: ")
if go_back == "Yes":
    print_menu()
else:
   print("We'll continue with your current choice")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i just posted the code so you can get a view of what i am talking about

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `while True` loop at all. It might cause problems with infinite looping. You can avoid it by calling a new function `check_if_wants_to_order_again` after a user has chosen his menu in print_menu().

```
def print_menu():
  print('1. American')
  print('2. Asian')
  print('3. Indian')
  print('4. Mexican')
  print('5. French')
  print('6. Italian')
  print('7. Seafood')
  print('8. Pizza')
  menu = input('\nChoose where you want to eat from-->')
  if menu == "1":
    american_menu()
  check_if_wants_to_order_again()

def american_menu():
  print('1. Dempsey Burger Pub')
  print('2. Redrock Canyon Grill-Wichita')
  print("3. Cheddar's Scratch Kitchen")
  print("4. Neighbors| Restaurant & Bar")
  print("5. The Kitchen")
  print("6. Firebirds Wood Fired Grill")
  print("7. Chicken and Pickle")
  american = input("\nChoose which American Restaurant--> ")
  if american == "1":
      print("\nCall Dempsey Burger Pub")

def check_if_wants_to_order_again():
  go_back = input("Will you like to try another menu option? Enter \"Yes\" or \"No\":")
  if go_back == "Yes":
    print_menu()
  else:
    print("We'll continue with your current choice")

print_menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `continue` your loop, you're calling `print_menu()` again, but you aren't doing any of the other things that need to follow `print_menu()` in order to prompt the user to make another choice.

Give this a shot:

```
# Define the menus as dictionaries.
# The key is the number that the user will pick,
# the value is the selected item.

# Main menu -- pick a cuisine.
main_menu = {
    "1": "American",
    "2": "Asian",
    "3": "Indian",
    "4": "Mexican",
    "5": "French",
    "6": "Italian",
    "7": "Seafood",
    "8": "Pizza",
}

# American restaurant menu.
american_menu = {
    "1": "Dempsey Burger Pub",
    "2": "Redrock Canyon Grill-Wichita",
    "3": "Cheddar's Scratch Kitchen",
    "4": "Neighbors| Restaurant & Bar",
    "5": "The Kitchen",
    "6": "Firebirds Wood Fired Grill",
    "7": "Chicken and Pickle",
}

# This dict maps each cuisine name to the appropriate submenu.
cuisine_menus = {
    "American": american_menu,
    # "Asian": asian_menu,
    # "French": french_menu,
    # ...
}

# This dict maps each restaurant name to its contact info.
contact_info = {
    "Dempsey Burger Pub": (
        "(316) 425-3831",
        "https://www.dempseysburgerpub.com/"
    ),
    "Redrock Canyon Grill-Wichita": (
        "(316) 636-1844",
        "https://www.redrockcanyongrill.com/"
    ),
    # ...
}

def print_menu(menu):
    """Print a menu, e.g. '1. American'..."""
    for k, v in menu.items():
        print(f"{k}. {v}")

def contact_restaurant(restaurant):
    """Contact a restaurant.  Raises KeyError if we don't have contact info."""
    phone, website = contact_info[restaurant]
    print(restaurant)
    print(f"Phone: {phone}")
    print(f"Website: {website}")
    # maybe do something with website to open a browser?  idk


# Interactive loop.  Go through the menus in turn,
# and repeat when done or when they enter something invalid.
# Break the loop once they finish picking a restaurant.
while True:
    # Main menu (pick a cuisine)
    print_menu(main_menu)
    pick = input('\nChoose where you want to eat from-->')
    # Error checking for invalid picks.
    if pick not in main_menu:
        print("Please select one of the listed options.")
        continue
    cuisine = main_menu[pick]
    if cuisine not in cuisine_menus:
        # This happens if they picked something that was in main_menu
        # but not in cuisine_menus yet because we haven't written that part.
        print("Oops!  Haven't implemented that one yet.")
        print(f"Try {', '.join(cuisine_menus)}")
        continue

    # Now we have a valid main menu pick that we can continue with.
    cuisine_menu = cuisine_menus[cuisine]

    # Print the menu and ask them to pick an item from that.
    print_menu(cuisine_menu)
    pick = input(f"\nChoose which {cuisine} Restaurant--> ")
    if pick not in cuisine_menu:
        print("Sorry, not an option.  Let's start over.")
        continue

    restaurant = cuisine_menu[pick]
    if restaurant not in contact_info:
        print(f"Oops, we don't have contact info for {restaurant}.")
        print("Let's start over...")
        continue
    
    print(f"\nCall {restaurant}")

    # Prompt them to start over.  If they don't, break the loop.
    pick = input("Will you like to try another menu option?: ")
    if pick != "Yes":
        print("We'll continue with your current choice")
        break

# Now the user has picked a restaurant to contact,
# so go ahead and contact them.
contact_restaurant(restaurant)
```

Note that all of the interaction happens inside the `while True` loop.  Any time there's a `continue` within that loop, it goes back to the `print_menu(main_menu)` at the start, and then continues from there.

Comment: Thank you very much but also, why did you put commas?

Comment: Because the code doesn't work without them.  (Try running the code I gave you exactly as I wrote it, and then try removing some of the commas.)

Comment: Ah, i see now. i'll have to look at it and see how i can tweak mine to run like that. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried reading and understanding the process for the codes, but they are a bit confusing, Is there a way you can tweak the original code so i understand it?

Comment: Which part doesn’t make sense?

Comment: the whole code, sorry. Now it runs and i can see it but mine has the function to go to the websites and order and phone number (btw do you have an idea to insert clickable phone numbers?...thanks in advance) but, it looks like steps were skipped and all, that's why it feels confusing. maybe it's the change of how you wrote it

Comment: Your code didn't have that function, but I left the part where it prints "Call Dempsey Burger" (except it prints whatever they picked, not just "Dempsey Burger").  That'd be where you put your function that does additional stuff.  I went back and added a bunch of comments to the code to help guide you through it, but you'll need to ask specific questions if you get stuck somewhere; I can't answer a question that you haven't asked.

Comment: Ah, ok. thank you. i will look at it and redo it, also could you add how i can put in individual websites and numbers because mine had the import webbrowser but since your code picks off from the menu, i want it to have where if i pick Dempsey, it has just dempsey's number rather than another restaurant having the same number and website

Comment: I'd probably create another dictionary that contains that information, similar to how `cuisine_menus` maps each `main_menu` number to the menu for that cuisine type.  Since you didn't include that part of your code I didn't translate it when I wrote my version, but if you want to go back and update your question again I could take a crack at it.

Comment: I went and added a `contact_restaurant` function as a placeholder for the thing you described, and added a `contact_info` dictionary that's able to hold the contact info for all the restaurants.  All you'd need to do to make it work from here is add code to `contact_restaurant` and then add the rest of the `cuisine_menus` and `contact_info` entries.

Comment: oh, thank you very much. I'll look at it and run through it